# Switching boot disk, have mirrored drives

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am switching out my SSD (which is my boot drive) as it is getting extremely slow speeds. I have 2 1TB drives in windows as a mirrored drive.

Since I am doing a fresh install of Windows on my new SSD, do I need to do anything to my mirrored drives (they are mirroed within windows, not hardware raid or anything like that) or will the new installation recognize them right away?

My OS is Windows 7.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new installation will not show the volumes on the disks immediately. You will have to go to Disk Management and there you will see them as *foreign*. Right click and select Import and they will be added properly.

More information can be found from Microsoft at [Move Disks to Another Computer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc753750.aspx).